# LINQ Select Expression on nested list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How would I go about looping through a nested list with Linq?

I have a nested list which looks like this:

```
var bookings = new List<List<Booking>>();
```

Inside the Booking class are booking details, and such

I want to loop through each indivudal list and extract the list which is nested by using Linq, but I'm struggling to do it :(

I'm not sure what method i should use with Linq, i've tried using SelectMany but i dont think I understand it well enough.

Comment: What output exactly are you aiming for?

Comment: `SelectMany` is the good way to do it. So what is the problem if you have tried that? ... and what is wrong about two nested `foreach`-cycles?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to flatten the list with `SelectMany`:

```
bookings.SelectMany((list) => list);
```

If you're trying to extract each individual list:

```
bookings.ForEach((list) => {
    // Do something with the nested list
});
```

If you're trying to filter the nested lists, but maintain those the lists:

```
bookings.Select((list) => list.Where((item) => item.Price > 20));
```

And so on.

`SelectMany` expects a function that turns each item in a list into a  `IEnumerable<T>` and then flattens the resulting `IEnumerable<T>` of `IEnumerable<T>`s into a `IEnumerable<T>`. By using `SelectMany` with an identity function `(list) => list` you're effectively doing nothing with each item in the list—they are already `IEnumerable<T>'s` and, as such, dont *need* any further transformation—`SelectMany` will then subsequently flatten the resulting `IEnumerable<T>` of `IEnumerable<T>`s.

Comment: I renamed `List<T>`s to `IEnumerable<T>`s. Doesn't change the concept but I'm certain C# pedants will pick that hole